# Linux command with scape character

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command

When I try to execute some command like this:

> > ssh host_1 "cat test_file | sed 's/$/\tOK/'"

I got this error:

> > Illegal variable name.

What is the problem?

Comment: can you change the `sed` command to something else until it works? I suspect the `$` is giving problems...

Comment: Btw I checked your code with my raspberry pi and my debain computer that works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to escape the dollar sign:

```
ssh host_1 "cat test_file | sed 's/\$/\\tOK/'"
```

Comment: This does not work with me. It gives me this error: Variable name must contain alphanumeric character.

Comment: It gives me this error: Variable name must contain alphanumeric character.

Comment: this is what I can seen with a contrived example: https://gist.github.com/AD7six/b108578e1bfd433f93b4

Comment: This is really getting me crazy!! I even tried to copy-paste your exact command, NO LUCK.

Comment: @TuaimiAA which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to escape special characters:

```
ssh host_1 "cat test_file | sed 's/\$/\\tOK/'"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run

```
ssh host_1 "cat test_file | sed 's/$/\tOK/'"
```

your local shell first performs parameter expansion on its arguments. The command is `ssh`, the first argument is `host_1`, and the second argument is `"cat test_file | sed 's/$/\tOK'"`. Since the second argument is in double quotes, parameter expansion is attemped. However, `$/` is not a valid parameter in `bash`. Note that the single quotes are just literal characters inside the double-quoted string; they do not protect the dollar sign from parameter expansion. So you need to escape the dollar sign as pointed out in the other questions.

Once the command is executed, the shell on the remote end receives the following string:

```
cat test_file | sed 's/$/\tOK'.
```

The double quotes are gone, as they are removed during quote removal by the local shell. The dollar sign is similarly unescaped now. And now, because the remote shell sees the first argument to `sed` as a single-quoted string, no parameter expansion is performed, and the dollar sign need not be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find what happened.

I got crazy while the answer worked for you and not for me. Your answers guys are perfectly correct. However the problem was that I'm using csh & not ksh, each one interprets the command (parameter expansion) differently.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Don't use csh unless you must.